# Cannot read property 'center' of undefined highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to place title in center of pie chart. I have a method call addTitle that it place title in center of pie chart. This method is executed by the load event. My code is the next:

```
addTitle = (char) ->
    console.log 'entra', char
    if char.title
      char.title.destroy()

    r = char.renderer
    x = char.series[0].center[0] + char.plotLeft //Series is undefined, Why?
    y = char.series[0].center[1] + char.plotTop //Series is undefined, Why?
    char.title = r.text('Series 1', 0, 0)
    .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px'
      }).hide()
    .add();

    bbox = char.title.getBBox();
    char.title.attr({
      x: x - (bbox.width / 2),
      y: y
    }).show();

 events: {
     load: () ->
         addTitle(this)
 }
```

Comment: what is char here ?? It looks like you are posting the algorithm instead of code , post your code properly or create a jsfiddle for proper understanding.

Comment: You can find `addTitle(this)` below the code. Anyway, how about this: `load: addTitle` and then in `addTitle` add as first line: `char = this` ? I guess JS compiled code makes some issues, could you attach generated code? Or maybe you are calling `addTitle()` somewhere else too?